# show exact result for each div after success AJAX callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am struggling trying to get the corresponding result for each item after successful AJAX callback. I am able to get the results, but not individually in each div from the item when there is more than one, each item displayed is getting all the results in the div and not just the corresponding one.

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
type: "HEAD",
url: image,
success: function(){
$(".block .image-sze").append(xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Length'));
}
});
```

Can someone help me to fix the above so it can show individual result for each item?

Comment: Can you make it return json type data which is an array and change different divs accordingly?

Comment: Hi Chandler, can you pls let me know how can I do that? Im seeing results are correct and displaying but for instance if I have 3 images displayed, each of those are displaying the 3 same results, when in fact what I need is that 1 item gets 1 result.

Answer (score 0):

The selector `$(".block .image-sze")` is only selecting the first class with `block`, use `$("*.block *.image-sze")` instead!

The "*" selects all tag that has the same class!

Hope this help?

Comment: I tried but it didn't change anything. Results are showing correctly for each item as I commented. So if I have 3 items displaying, each of them is getting the 3 results, instead I need that 1 item gets 1 result, and with corresponding order.

Comment: Can you fiddle your example?

Comment: Please write out all the code you have tested to enable me understand you better so i can help!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you're looking for something like this?

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json'
    url: url, 
    success: function(json){
        $('#image1').html(json['image1']);
        $('#image2').html(json['image2']);
    }
});
```

And you're calling from url with something like this

```
public function somefunction() {
    $json = array();
    $json['image1'] = 'image1';
    $json['image2'] = 'image2';
    echo json_encode($json); 
}
```